# Parse - withinMiles and withinKilometers is not working?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, geopoints

I don't have any problem on building or running my app. 
I stored on Parse a geopoint and I am comparing with another one created in-running.

I am assigning them the same value (I already tried to assign a different location, by changing a digit on latitude and longitude also)

Distance between them is 0 meters or 1 meter.

This doesn't work:

```
query.whereKey("Coordinate", nearGeoPoint: currentLocation, withinKilometers: 15.0)
```

This works:

```
query.whereKey("Coordinate", nearGeoPoint: currentLocation)
```

And this doesn't work:

```
query.whereKey("Coordinate", nearGeoPoint: currentLocation, withinKilometers: 155555555.0)
```

This makes no sense for me.

Comment: What does `currentLocation` actually look like?  What does "doesn't work" mean?  How do the actual results compare to the expected results?

Comment: When I say "doesn't work",  it means it doesn't returns that location 1 meter far from currentLocation. It only returns when I don't use withinKilometers

Comment: currentLocation is a PFGeoPoint and when I print it: "<PFGeoPoint: 0x7feeb25fbc40, latitude: 51.509980, longitude: -0.133700>"